# Ionic - How to loop over JSON Objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm a dummy when it comes to Angular and I'm currently building a ionic app ( similar to Instagram ) for a school project. I have HTML code that is ready to be filled with content from my Database. I have a provider set up and I managed to display a single title. But now what I was wondering is how can I loop through all table entries to show all Posts in the same HTML format that I've written for posts.
[image: In this image you can see what my data object looks like right now when I do console.log on it]

If anyone knows a good tut or anything please let me know!

Comment: you should really try following the tutorials angular has on their website. It covers such topics. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/

Comment: ionic uses angular, same syntax:  let item of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To loop over Array:

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of data">
    <li>{{item.description}}</li>
</ul>
```

This will loop over your array.

Comment: The html isn't visible. You need to format it as a code.

Comment: It worked in combination with your other comment and a Youtube video, tried a thousand times in similar ways lol.. Life of a programmer sucks sometimes, glad I can go on, thanks!